# Should scripts that require sudo fail if they don't have it, or use sudo and prompt?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

I have a script which gives me fine-grained control over my backlight brightness and requires `sudo` to run. It's essentially this:

```
backlight="/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
echo $1 | tee $backlight
```

and lives at `~/bin/backlight-adjust`. The script needs `sudo` privileges, because `tee $backlight` is writing to a privileged location. So it'll fail if it's not run with `sudo`.

This approach has a problem, because I can't just run `sudo backlight-adjust`, because `~/bin` is not in the `$PATH` in the `sudo` environment, only in my environment. So I'd have to to run `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" backlight-adjust` or something similar.

Alternatively, I could have written it like this:

```
backlight="/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
echo $1 | sudo tee $backlight
```

and prompt me for the password.

The second approach works better for me because I don't have to remember to type sudo; it'll prompt me. And I can keep my `$PATH` intact. This feels more convenient overall, but **are there any reasons why I shouldn't do it the second way?**

(I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 and my shell is GNU bash 4.2.45, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'm running a modified Debian (LMDE) and my `sudo` actually keeps my `$PATH` by default so I don't have this issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Personally, I would use a different approach. Make an alias for your script. Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent in other shells)

```
alias backlight-adjust='sudo ~/bin/backlight-adjust'
```

That way, you don't need to worry about remembering to run it with `sudo` and you don't need to add the `sudo` to the script. It will be completely transparent to you and simply ask for your password when you try and run `backlight-adjust`.

Comment: This seems like a very sensible approach, and the one with minimal impact on the rest of the system. +1.

Comment: @JohnFeminella On the other hand, if you ever want to share this script with anyone else, they'll need the alias, too. Personally, I don't see any reason not to put `sudo` in the actual script, especially since that allows you to easily see which elements of the script actually require root permissions.

Comment: @KyleStrand no they won't. The command called by the script will simply complain about not having access.

Comment: @terdon I recognize that I could have been slightly clearer, but presumably you know what I meant: the recipient of the script will face the same problem originally faced by the author of the script, and as a conscientious script-sharer, the author should also share their personal solution to this particular usage dilemma.

Comment: @KyleStrand yes, but there was no problem, the only issue the OP had was that he didn't want to "have to remember to type sudo" apart from that, the script will be perfectly portable. My point is that the alias is completely optional and doesn't solve anything, it just makes it easier to use.

Comment: While this works, it is a (minor) security risk. From a security perspective, any script that runs as root should be owned by root. So just as to edit system files you call `sudo vi`, you would call the script as root. If you want the script to be available to multiple users consider using placing your script in `/usr/local/bin` (should be on the path for most distros). You would then alias `backlight='sudo /usr/local/bin/backlight-adjust`. Note: I also suggest you use the full path in scritps and aliases as "~" or "../" are abmigious are also a (minor) security risk.

Comment: @terdon For a script this simple, I consider a usage-inconvenience to be a (minor) problem to be solved. In this context, the alias is indeed a solution.

Answer (score 7):

I can't see why it could be incorrect --- although I normally prefer that commands would not ask things to me, so that they are scriptable. You can tweak `/etc/sudoers` to have that `sudo` working without a password.

But... why not adding

```
chgrp  one-of-your-groups-here /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness     
chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

in your `/etc/rc.local` and forget about `sudo`?

(In Ubuntu if you are able to use `sudo` you are in the *sudo* group, so you can use `chgrp sudo  /sys...` and be happy with it.)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could add

```
Defaults        env_keep +="PATH"
```

to your `/etc/sudoers` file.

Answer (score 2):

You state *sudo backlight-adjust, because ~/bin is not in the $PATH in the sudo environment*

So why depend on that?
I think you should just change that line to `/home/user/bin/backlight-adjust` and it will work.

But I'd really like Terdon's solution of using an alias also. Or you could place your script in `/usr/bin/` and it will be available for every user (incl. root)

Comment: Yes, but it's annoying to do that. Otherwise, what was the point of putting it in my $PATH in the first place? Also, I like having it in `~/bin` because then it's under my home's dotfiles repository, so it stays in version-control.

Comment: @JohnFeminella by the way, there's no reason to change path, just use the `-E` flag to preserve the environment: `sudo -E command`

Comment: @terdon That doesn't work in Debian; it's overridden for security reasons. You'd have to pass the environment variables explicitly, as I mentioned in my question (`sudo env "PATH=$PATH" ...`).

Answer (score 1):

Can't give a general rule... if the script/program is designed to do some reconfiguring (e.g. a printer) and be called by regular users, it has to. Otherwise, I'd leave well enough alone: If a regular user runs it, just fail (either as a result of an explicit check, or just because it isn't allowed to do something).

Elevated privileges should be handed out sparingly, if at all. Switching to higher privilege is tricky, better leave it to the experts (i.e., `sudo(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use something like `${SUDO}` in my scripts, so that the caller can set it if needed, or `${SUDO:-sudo}` to use it by default.

In your specific case, I’m with the accepted answer, though.

Answer (score -1):

Put the script (without the `sudo`) in a proper user-wide location, like `/bin`, and then do this:

```
sudo chown root /bin/backlight-adjust
sudo chmod 4755 /bin/backlight-adjust
```

This works by setting the setuid flag, which means it will always be run as the file owner. For details please read http://major.io/2007/02/13/chmod-and-the-mysterious-first-octet/. I don't really know all that much about how this works, I just found it googling based on something I thought I read a few years ago.

Comment: Shell scripts cannot be setuid any more, thanks goodness… This is an utterly evil answer, you know. Security-wise, especially.

Comment: @mirabilos Its only dangerous if the group or general write flags are on. The risk with setuid is that anyone with write permissions for the file can run anything they like as if they were the user, and so it is these write permissions that need to be protected. `4755` means always executed as owner, owner can read, write, and execute, group can read and execute, and users can read and execute, which is the standard permission level for things any user should be allowed to do with root permissions.

Comment: @mirabilos And the idea that shell scripts with setuid introduce more vulnerabilities than binaries with setuid is just silly; binaries are not immune to the ptrace exploit either, which is the main exploit that takes advantage of setuid.

Comment: All current Unix-like OSes forbid setuid scripts. This is just a fact. Ask them for reasons yourself if you don't believe me. Start with OpenBSD.